# Controllers not loading up JSON file Angular

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have three files - app.js, controllers.js, services.js. There are a few others I want to add if I get the approach to work. I see the code going into the angular.module section of mainApp, then the services and controllers. However, no error occurs and no data is coming back and the controller methods are not called at all (only controllers are initialized from the looks of it). I tried forcing a call using init() but no luck there too. What am I doing wrong?

Here is app.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module('MainApp', ['test.services', 'test.controllers']);
```

Controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('test.controllers', []); 
app.controller('TestCtrl', [$scope, 'TestService', function($scope, TestService)

    var promise = TestService.makeHttpRequest(../../src/testFile.json); 

    promise.then(function(data){            
        $scope.results = data;
        console.log($scope.results);
    });
}]);
```

Doesn't work. Below approach also doesn't get any data.

```
var app = angular.module('test.controllers', []); 
app.controller('TestCtrl', [$scope, $http, function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('../../src/testFile.json').then(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data.data;
        console.log(data);
    }); 
}]);
```

services.js

```
var appServices = angular.module('test.services', []);

//Does the same thing, but get call moved to services
```

Index.html

```
  <body class="bg-blue mainContainer" ng-app="MainApp">
        <div id="content-container" ng-contoller="TestCtrl" class="container main-container">{{results}}</div>
    <div id="content-container" ng-contoller="MainController" class="container main-container" ng-init="loadResults()">
    </body>
```

Comment: remove the dependencies test.services and test.controllers, that is not needed, make that []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `testFile.json` needs to be available by your http server for it to form a response.

Also you are not invoking your controller from the DOM properly.

Here is a rough example for your html:

```
<body class="bg-blue mainContainer" ng-app="MainApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  </div>
</body>
```

And then format your JavaScript as so:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('MainApp', ['test.controllers']);

var app = angular.module('test.controllers', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function() {
  console.info('TestCtrl');
});
```

Comment: I am using node.js and opened a http-server through command prompt. Index.html is where the code exists, and all JS/CSS load fine. How can I check if the testFile.json is available by server? If I try localhost/src/json/testFile.json, I see the JSON coming in fine.

Comment: The easiest way is finding the absolute location of the file. Is your src directory the public directory?

Comment: Ok I tried using physical location and the llocalhost:8080/src/ path to the file in get request. Both didn't work. The problem is the controller methods are not getting called at all. I don't get the to the actual http.get call at all.

Comment: Looks like your controller declaration is incorrect. I've added an example to my original answer. Hope that can help you in the right direction?

Comment: tried. still doesn't work. the json file exists here http://localhost:8080/src/testFile.json, the controller appears to be called but no code within it is executing. this line: app.controller('TestCtrl',... ) is called, but nothing within it is called. Any other ideas?

Comment: Now I'm getting this error - Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
 !!

Comment: Can you post a plunkr/jsbin/jsfiddle and I can help solve it for you? It seems like you're not matching controllers to their designated areas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90831/discussion-between-loser-coder-and-rish).

Answer (score 1):

Could this be your problem?

```
ng-contoller="MainController"
```

Notice the missing R in the word contRoller
edit:
Btw, both of your controller functions seem ok to me.
Only thing i do different is name everything as a string in array, like ['$http', function($http){}]